# JavaFX Chart points are cutten off (using own bound values)

Tags: css, javafx, charts, axis, points

[image]

As you can see in the picture the points on the highest and lowest axis are only half visible. If you need more code snippets, let me know. I have also tried to fix it with pane.setPadding... but nothing happens. Also in the CSS part !important does nothing.

Java Code:

```
public DistrictsChart(TimePeriod timePeriod, Pane pane) {
    Futures.addCallback(Main.getInstance().getPersonRepository().getPlaceInfectedData(timePeriod, PersonState.SUSPECTED), (Callback<Map<String, Long>>) suspectedData ->
            Futures.addCallback(Main.getInstance().getPersonRepository().getPlaceInfectedData(timePeriod, PersonState.CONFIRMED), (Callback<Map<String, Long>>) confirmedData ->
                    Futures.addCallback(Main.getInstance().getPersonRepository().getPlaceInfectedData(timePeriod, PersonState.RECOVERED), (Callback<Map<String, Long>>) recoveredData ->
                            Futures.addCallback(Main.getInstance().getPersonRepository().getPlaceInfectedData(timePeriod, PersonState.DEATH), (Callback<Map<String, Long>>) deathData -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                // Clear old chart
                                pane.getChildren().clear();

                                CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
                                xAxis.setLabel("Stadtteile");

                                NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Infizierte", 0, getMaxValue(suspectedData, confirmedData, recoveredData, deathData), 1);
                                yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

                                StackedBarChart<String, Number> barChart = new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

                                XYChart.Series<String, Number> dataSeriesSuspected = new XYChart.Series<>();
                                dataSeriesSuspected.getData().addAll(suspectedData.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList()));

                                barChart.getData().addAll(dataSeriesInfected, dataSeriesRecovered, dataSeriesDead, dataSeriesSuspected);

                                barChart.setLegendVisible(false);

                                pane.getChildren().add(barChart);
                            }), Main.getInstance().getMySQL().getPool()), Main.getInstance().getMySQL().getPool()), Main.getInstance().getMySQL().getPool()), Main.getInstance().getMySQL().getPool());
}

private int getMaxValue(Map<String, Long> suspected, Map<String, Long> confirmed, Map<String, Long> recovered, Map<String, Long> death) {
    Set<String> places = new HashSet<>();
    places.addAll(suspected.keySet());
    places.addAll(confirmed.keySet());
    places.addAll(recovered.keySet());
    places.addAll(death.keySet());

    return places.stream().mapToInt(s -> (int) (suspected.getOrDefault(s, 0L) + confirmed.getOrDefault(s, 0L)
            + recovered.getOrDefault(s, 0L) + death.getOrDefault(s, 0L))).max().orElse(0);
}
```

CSS Code:

```
.chart-content, .chart {
    -fx-padding: 2; <- Not Working
}

.chart .text {
    -fx-fill: primary-text-color;
}

.chart-series-area-line {
    -fx-stroke: primary-color;
}

.chart-area-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: primary-color;
}

.chart-vertical-grid-lines, .chart-horizontal-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: primary-background-color;
    -fx-stroke-dash-array: 1;
}

.axis {
    -fx-tick-mark-visible: false;
    -fx-minor-tick-visible: false;
    -fx-tick-label-gap: 8;
    -fx-border-color: bar-color;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply have the upper bound of each axis be one more step greater than the max value in the series?

Comment: because it doesn't look good. For example, with an entry of "1", half of it would be empty: https://i.imgur.com/sI4iCJv.png. If I lift it just a little high, it doesn't look good either: https://i.imgur.com/bUPL4fz.png